# How can I get a file using chrome.downloads API

Tags: file, google-chrome-extension, download

I have a chrome extension that detects when a file is being dowloaded and it has to send the file to a server that will analyze it.

The problem is that I don´t know how can I get this file that has just been downloaded. I tried with downloadItem.filename but it is only giving me the name and not the entire url or file.

Comment: There's no way. You can send the URL to the server so it downloads the file remotely.

Comment: But un that way, Won't the server need same permissions as user to download the file if you are, for example, logged on a web sites?

Comment: Well then you'll have to download the URL in your extension and then send it.